# how to change column names in rshiny using reactive function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am uploading one csv file and to standardize the code I want to change the column names. so I am using following code:

`Prv_mnth_so1 <- reactive({data.frame(lapply(data_uploaded1(),trimws))})`
`colnames(Prv_mnth_so1()) <- c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo")`
but this throws an error
**Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
52: server [#12]
Error in colnames(Prv_mnth_so1()) <- c("GST_ward", "Category", "order_and_section",  :
invalid (NULL) left side of assignment**

it means I can't assign () operator on right side but I am not able to fix this issue

Comment: try `colnames(Prv_mnth_so1) <-  c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo")`; the double brackets on the left may be the problem.

Comment: @Lime no, `Prv_mnth_so1` is a `reactive`, so the double brackets are ok (because a `reactive` is basically a function you have to execute). I suspect that it doesn't work because you can't change the values of a `reactive` outside of the `reactive` itself

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the values of a `reactive` inside the `reactive` itself, because it is basically a function you evaluate (therefore you have to use the brackets).

You can either 1. try to change it directly when creating `Prv_mnth_so1` or 2. later in another reactive context:

1.

```
Prv_mnth_so1 <- reactive({
  new_table <- data.frame(lapply(data_uploaded1(),trimws))
  colnames(new_table) <- c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo")
  new_table
  })
```

2. 

```
Prv_mnth_so1 <- reactive({data.frame(lapply(data_uploaded1(),trimws))})

output$table <- renderTable({
  table_data <- Prv_mnth_so1()
  colnames(table_data) <- c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo")
  table_data
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried option 1 as follows: ```output$state_lst <- reactive({
  Prv_mnth_so1 <- data.frame(lapply(data_uploaded1(),trimws))
  colnames(Prv_mnth_so1) <- c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo","Product_Number","Orders_Status","Option_Number","SRN",
                              "Quantity_On_Hand","Invoice_Or_Billing_Id","Lc_Amount","Clearance_date")
  Prv_mnth_so1$state <- sub("\\-.*", "", Prv_mnth_so1$"GST_ward")
  state_lst <- data.frame(unique(Prv_mnth_so1$state))
  state_lst
    })```

Comment: but getting following error  Warning: Error in <-: 'names' attribute [12] must be the same length as the vector [0]
  [No stack trace available]
    Plenase note that data_uploaded1 is the reactive file that i have uploaded using upload button  as follows ```data_uploaded1 <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file1
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)
  })``` file1 is the id of uploaded file  ```fileInput("file1", "Previous Month close Sales office")```

Comment: Tried option 2  there also getting similar error:
  ```Prv_mnth_so2 <- reactive({
  Prv_mnth_so1 <- data.frame(lapply(data_uploaded1(),trimws))
  Prv_mnth_so1
  })
output$state_lst1 <- reactive ({
Prv_mnth_so2 <- Prv_mnth_so2() 
colnames(Prv_mnth_so2) <- c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo","Product_Number","Orders_Status","Option_Number","SRN",
"Quantity_On_Hand","Invoice_Or_Billing_Id","Lc_Amount","Clearance_date")
 Prv_mnth_so2$state <- data.frame(sub("\\-.*", "", Prv_mnth_so2$"GST_ward"))
  state_lst <- data.frame(unique(Prv_mnth_so2$state))
  state_lst
    })```

Comment: then please edit your question above to include a complete minimal reproducible example (running shiny app). Maybe the reason is that your input data is not ready yet, so try to add `req` with the needed input data

Comment: server <- function(input, output) {
  data_uploaded1 <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file1
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)
  })
  Prv_mnth_so2 <- reactive({
    Prv_mnth_so1 <- data.frame(lapply(data_uploaded1(),trimws))
    Prv_mnth_so1
  })
  output$state_lst1 <- reactive ({
    Prv_mnth_so2 <- Prv_mnth_so2()

Comment: colnames(Prv_mnth_so2) <- c("GST_ward","Category","order_and_section","combo","Product_Number","Orders_Status","Option_Number","SRN","Quantity_On_Hand","Invoice_Or_Billing_Id","Lc_Amount","Clearance_date")
Prv_mnth_so2$state <- data.frame(sub("\\-.*", "", Prv_mnth_so2$"GST_ward"))
    state_lst <- data.frame(unique(Prv_mnth_so2$state))
    state_lst
  })}
shinyApp(ui, server)

Comment: input data format                                                                                                                                        GST ward Category Order & Section Combo Product_Number Orders Status Option_Number Shipment Reference number Quantity_On_Hand Invoice_Or_Billing_Id Lc_Amount Received month
Assam-18 ESC J9K619328319 J9K6193283193C743PC 3C743PC         Not invoiced     7SCA47333373 150 CR4786386A 108 Cleared on or Before May ' 2020

Comment: working ui ```ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Inventory Management" , titleWidth = 800)
  ,dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("data", tabName = "Page1" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
      ,menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Page2" , icon=icon("tachometer"))))
  ,dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("Page1",fluidRow(column(3,fileInput("file1", "Previous Month close Sales office")))
       ,fluidRow(column(3,box(dataTableOutput("state_lst1")))))
       ,tabItem("Page2", p("Analysis Outcome"),fluidRow(column(3,box(dataTableOutput("state_list1")))))
            )))```

Comment: Please edit it into your original question, then it's easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: i have posted same question with new thread    as I wasn't aware how to edit original post                                                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359227/issue-in-data-processing-and-column-names-in-rshiny-using-reactive-function

Comment: Please **don't** post new questions but edit your question. Directly below the tags of the question you can click on "edit" to edit your question